# How to update failed transaction detail in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

I am using `drupal commerce` to built a e-commerce site .

My problem is when a transaction is failed or get a late response then the transaction is not created.

Can i create it manually or i have to ? if yes then how?

Or is their any other way to attach my transaction detail to `order` .

Any help most appriciate. Thank you.

Comment: This question is very vague. What payment module are you using? This sounds like a bug in the module or perhaps PHP is dying before the request times out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the failed transaction from order id as shown below:

```
<?php
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
  $result = $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_payment_transaction')
    ->propertyCondition('order_id', $order->order_id)
    ->propertyOrderBy('transaction_id', 'DESC')
    ->range(0, 1)
    ->execute();
?>
```

Then load transaction using `commerce_payment_transaction_load($transaction_id)` & update transaction object as shown below:

```
<?php
//Use following line instead of loading transaction in order to create new transaction object
//$transaction = commerce_payment_transaction_new('commerce_payment_example', $order->order_id);
$transaction = commerce_payment_transaction_load($transaction_id);
$transaction->amount = $charge['amount'];
$transaction->currency_code = $charge['currency_code'];
$transaction->status = COMMERCE_PAYMENT_STATUS_SUCCESS;
commerce_payment_transaction_save($transaction);
?>
```

You can set a cron to periodically check failed transaction & check status of same at Payment Gateway & update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your interest but in my case transaction is not created yet. i.e, if customer close the window just after payment.